# Django models.Model superclass

Tags: python, django

I would like to create a models.Model class that doesn't became part of the database but just an interface to other models (I want to avoid repeating code).

Something like that:

```
class Interface(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.TextField()

class Foo(Interface):
    c = models.IntegerField()

class Bar(Interface):
    d = models.CharField(max_length='255')
```

So my database should have only Foo (with a,b,c collumns) and Bar (with a,b,d) but not the table Interface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

["Abstract base classes"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common information into a number of other models. You write your base class and put `abstract=True` in the Meta class. This model will then not be used to create any database table. Instead, when it is used as a base class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child class.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that but with the `abc` module. I'll try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can define your classes like this:

```
from django.db import models

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Student(CommonInfo):
    home_group = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```