# How to use base class in models.py but NOT have django create a table for the base class?

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django models.Model superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625010/django-models-model-superclass)

By default, if you inherit a model class, django will create a separate table for the base class. Is there any way to use base class (so that I can have the same columns in all derived models), but NOT have django create that base table, but instead, create derived tables with all those same columns?

For example:

```
class MyBaseModel(models.Model):
    createdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

class A(MyBaseModel):
    nameA ...

class B(MyBaseModel):
    nameB ...

#I want 2 tables created, A with 2 columns(nameA, createdate) and B with 2 columns.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

The base classes should contain:

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```